# React images won't load even with require suntax

Tags: reactjs

I am building a project but i am facing an issue where React doesn’t load the images even with the require syntax `<img src={require('./images/Jonas.jpg')} alt="test" />`

It works perfectly fine when i import the image `import image from './images/Jonas.jpg'` but for some reason it is not working with require which is absolutely crucial for the project...

Any ideas what might be the problem here ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file-loader` for this

Follow these steps

`npm install file-loader --save-dev`

Then add the loader to your webpack config.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
      test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
             name: '[path][name].[ext]'
      }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do i use the same syntax to load the image with file-loader ?

Comment: Yes, that was your requirement. You can use `<img src={require('./images/Jonas.jpg')} alt="test" />` for your image

Comment: I am new to webpack and i created the **webpack,config.js**  but it is empty and when i paste the code part you provided it gives me errors :/ is it supposed to be inside an object?

Comment: I think this documentation will help you with your problem. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/